# Why would the priests bribe guards to lie when given clear evidence that Jesus was immortal? (Mt. 28:11-12)

Tags: history, historical-jesus, jews, logic

Logic speaks to me that, no matter HOW much I hated someone, if given clear testimony from the best of the Roman guard that the guy fulfilled his own prediction and was raised from the dead by supernatural forces, I would either:

A. repent & join his team or, at the least,
B. live in constant fear that I'd be zapped by a lighting bolt for calling for Jesus' execution

I CERTAINLY wouldn't double down on my error by paying the guards to lie and perpetuate a claim that he was truly mortal and still dead.

Do these actions by the priests add up for you logically and, if so, how? Appreciate your thoughts!

> While the women were on their way, some of the guards went into the city and reported to the chief priests everything that had happened.
> When the chief priests had met with the elders and devised a plan, they gave the soldiers a large sum of money,
> telling them, “You are to say, ‘His disciples came during the night and stole him away while we were asleep.’
> If this report gets to the governor, we will satisfy him and keep you out of trouble.”
> So the soldiers took the money and did as they were instructed. And this story has been widely circulated among the Jews to this very day.
> — [Matthew 28:11–15 (NIV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+28&version=NIV)

Comment: I've dealt with lots of people who are emotionally invested in certain views. It is virtually impossible to argue them out of it - it doesn't matter how strong and clear the evidence is. Often, they just 'double down', as the priests do here. What exactly were they thinking? Who knows.

Comment: Remember that these sorts of people are described in the Gospels as liars, murderers, and sons of the Devil, by Jesus.

Comment: Or they were thinking: "*If these troublemakers can fool even ‘the best of the Roman guard’, just think what they might do with the common people. We'd better cut off this nonsense while we still can.*"

Answer (score 2):

OP: "if given clear testimony from the best of the Roman guard that the guy fulfilled his own prediction and was raised from the dead by supernatural forces,"

There's a bit of background that might help.  The Sanhedrin generally and the chief priests specifically didn't see it themselves.  They can't really rely on the testimony of the unclean guards.  And they could interpret that some guards did not report the same thing; some left; only some said "wow" (Mt. 28:11).

At the same time, the elders also must have realized that Daniel's 70 weeks of 7 had been fulfilled.  And as the OP said, Jesus had told them He will resurrect on the third day.  What did all this mean to their position, their pocketbooks, their piety?

Tell everyone the body was stolen.  (this later has morphed into the swoon theory that Christ only appeared to die on the cross, but was resuscitated in the cool tomb)

So, to answer the OP, it either wasn't clear to the elders that Christ had risen from the dead per partial testimony from the unclean Roman guards or if it was clear, they clearly would have understood what that meant for them.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus provided an answer to this question at the end of the parable of the rich man and Lazarus:

> And he said unto him, If they hear not Moses and the prophets, neither will they be persuaded, though one rose from the dead. (Luke 16:31)

The religious leaders of the day had departed from the teachings of Moses and the prophets (e.g. see Matt. 23:2-3); the praise of the world mattered more to them than doing the will of God (see Matt. 23:23-25). If Jesus' message were true, it undermined the things they cared about (money, power, etc.), so they preferred to believe it was not true.

Similar sentiments are sometimes found in skeptical circles today. Some so desperately wish for God not to exist or for sexual immorality not to be sinful, that no amount of evidence will convince them to believe something they do not want to be true. It is tragic when people spin in circles around moral arguments for God's existence ([example](https://youtu.be/aFVMfWfhjN8)), preferring not to condemn even atrocious violence as wrong because, in doing so, they acknowledge that right & wrong exist.